# Is the OpenCPU public server still available? API specs appear to have changed

Tags: r, opencpu

I am trying to update a R app on the OpenCPU public server (https://cloud.opencpu.org/).
With the new 2.2.0 OpenCPU release, all previous user payloads have apparently been wiped out (including mine).
The CI webhook is still up and running though. However, it systematically rejects the R package that I am trying to push through. Note that my app/CI used to work very well with previous OpenCPU versions. Error given is "server timeout".
Could not find any relevant info for this in the docs ([OpenCPU help](https://www.opencpu.org/help.html))
Is the public CI flow still available? Are other devs experiencing the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can now confirm that the OpenCPU server is actually fully operational.
My web-app is now fixed. Works well. The problem was from my side.

Sharing here my findings, so it can be useful for others:

1. My custom R package was trying to import too many external packages. I trimmed down the imports list to the strict minimum.
2. I set my custom package `lazyload` flag to `false`

The CI webhook now processes any new push to the Github branch and the corresponding package gets rebuilt smoothly server side.